# How can I combine two Rails 4 where queries that query either side of a boolean condition?

Tags: ruby, performance, ruby-on-rails-4, where-clause, rails-postgresql

### Question:

Is there a way to combine the following two queries (including the assignments) into one query?  I'm not sure how much time I'd really save.  In other words, I'm not sure if it is worth it, but I'd like to be as efficient as possible.

```
@contacts = @something.user.contacts.where.not(other_user_id: 0)
@user_contacts = @something.user.contacts.where(other_user_id: 0)
```

### More context:

Here is my contacts table from schema.rb:

```
  create_table "contacts", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "profile_picture"
    t.string   "phone_number"
    t.integer  "other_user_id"
  end
```

And here is the important stuff from the users table:

```
  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    ...
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "second_name"
  end
```

And here is the pertinent information of the models:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
  validates :user_id, presence: true

  def get_email_from_name
    self.email
  end
end

[...]

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts
  has_many :relationships,
           foreign_key: 'follower_id',
           dependent: :destroy
  has_many :reverse_relationships,
           foreign_key: 'followed_id',
           class_name: 'Relationship',
           dependent: :destroy
  has_many :commitments,
           class_name: 'Commitment',
           dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followers,
           through: :reverse_relationships
  has_many :followed_users,
           through: :relationships,
           source: :followed
  [...]

  before_save { email.downcase! || email }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email,
            presence: true,
            format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
            uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  [...]

  def follow!(other_user)
    relationships.create!(followed_id: other_user.id)
    if create_contact?(self, id, other_user.id)
      create_contact(other_user.name,
                           other_user.email,
                           self.id,
                           other_user.id,
                           other_user.gravatar_url)
    elsif create_contact?(other_user, other_user.id, id)
      create_contact(name, email, other_user.id, id, gravatar_url)
    end
  end

  def create_contact?(user, followed_id, follower_id)
    user.admin? && ! Relationship.where(followed_id: followed_id, follower_id: follower_id).empty?
  end

  def create_contact(name, email, user_id, other_user_id, profile_picture)
    Contact.create!(name: name,
                         email: email,
                         user_id: user_id,
                         other_user_id: other_user_id,
                         profile_picture: profile_picture)
  end

  def unfollow!(other_user)
    relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_user.id).destroy
    Contact.destroy_all(user_id: self.id, other_user_id: other_user.id)
  end

  [...]
end
```

The other contacts that may not have an account with the website (yet), and I'd like to distinguish that in the view.  So I keep track of which contacts I import through Google contacts using the `omniauth` gem.  For the other contacts, I gather the other users that are friends with `current_user`.

### Goal:

I'd like to save these two record collections to use in the view, but I'd like to avoid looking through all the user's contacts twice, checking the same column in each pass-through.

Any ideas?  I'm sure there are lots of ways this can be done, and I'd like to learn as much as I can from this!  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array#partition` to split up the array in memory, after the query was performed.

```
@user_contacts, @contacts = @something.user.contacts.partition{|u| other.id == 0 }
```

However checking for this magic `0` id is smelly. You should try to get rid of such special cases whenever possible.

Comment: Sweet, thanks!  The situation on the smelly 0 is this: I gather contacts in two different ways, one of which includes collecting contact information from the other users who have accounts and who you are friends with.  So if a contact has an `other_user_id` that is not 0, it matches the `user_id` of a user that created an account.  The other contacts are not signed up on the site, so they do not have an `other_user_id`.  Do you know of a better way I could keep track of that distinction?

Comment: If you post the model we can see whether there is a better solution. It is hard to say with so little context.

Comment: I gave a little more context in my question if you are still interested :)

Comment: Can you also show the model, at least the associations please? It allows us to better understand how things are wired up.

Comment: Thanks for your continued interest.  I have updated my question with the important model information.

Comment: Sorry to tell you that, but you seem to keep missing the important parts. It looks like `other_user_id` is never used in your code, is that right? The only important thing here are the relations (has_many, belongs_to etc.).

Comment: That's because I haven't really started using it yet.  It is a way for me to distinguish between the contacts that were imported through Gmail and the ones that are users of the site.  This is important for me to distinguish because I have access to profile pictures of the users of the site.

Comment: Basically it is a way for me to know whether a contact has an account with the site or not.  I haven't foreseen all the potential, if any, of having this distinction.  But if it turns out I don't need it, I'll get rid of it.

Comment: How about using two different objects for that? One `User` model for users of the site, which handles logins etc. The `User` model then has one `Contact`, which represents the shared "address book" logic between users and imported data. This is probably how I would do it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I'll consider it, but for now, I think what I have is working pretty good.  Thanks for your help with the partition method though!

Answer (score 1):

It is not the best solution, but if you think partition hard to understand, it can be an optional.

```
@user_contacts, @users = [], []
@something.user.contacts.each do |record|
    if record.other_user_id == 0
       @user_contacts << record
    else
       @users << record
    end
end
```